# what happens during nic master failover?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

During NIC master failover, will the mac address of bond0 change?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

#### fail_over_mac

Specifies whether `active-backup` mode should set all slaves to the same MAC address at enslavement (the traditional behavior), or, when enabled, perform special handling of the bond's MAC address in accordance with the selected policy.

Possible values are:

- `none` or `0`

This setting disables `fail_over_mac`, and causes bonding to set all slaves of an active-backup bond to the same MAC address at enslavement time.  This is the default.

- `active` or `1`

The "active" `fail_over_mac` policy indicates that the MAC address of the bond should always be the MAC address of the currently active slave.  The MAC address of the slaves is not changed; instead, the MAC address of the bond changes during a failover.

This policy is useful for devices that cannot ever alter their MAC address, or for devices that refuse incoming broadcasts with their own source MAC (which interferes with the ARP monitor).

The down side of this policy is that every device on the network must be updated via gratuitous ARP, vs. just updating a switch or set of switches (which often takes place for any traffic, not just ARP traffic, if the switch snoops incoming traffic to update its tables) for the traditional method.  If the gratuitous ARP is lost, communication may be disrupted.

When this policy is used in conjunction with the mii monitor, devices which assert link up prior to being able to actually transmit and receive are particularly susceptible to loss of the gratuitous ARP, and an appropriate `updelay` setting may be required.

- `follow` or `2`

The "follow" `fail_over_mac` policy causes the MAC address of the bond to be selected normally (normally the MAC address of the first slave added to the bond).  However, the second and subsequent slaves are not set to this MAC address while they are in a backup role; a slave is programmed with the bond's MAC address at failover time (and the formerly active slave receives the newly active slave's MAC address).

This policy is useful for multiport devices that either become confused or incur a performance penalty when multiple ports are programmed with the same MAC address.

The default policy is `none`, unless the first slave cannot change its MAC address, in which case the active policy is selected by default.